# Hazelcast. register IExecutorService

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, executorservice, executor

I am reading Hazelcast documentation (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Computing/Executor_Service/Implementing_a_Runnable_Task.html)

To manage Executor in cloud environment, hazelcast retrieve Executor like ...

```
public class MasterMember {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    IExecutorService executor = hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService( "exec" );
    for ( int k = 1; k <= 1000; k++ ) {
      Thread.sleep( 1000 );
      System.out.println( "Producing echo task: " + k );
      executor.execute( new EchoTask( String.valueOf( k ) ) );
    }
    System.out.println( "EchoTaskMain finished!" );
  }
}
```

However, I could not find the part which register ExecutorService named `exec`. I would like to know how to register Executor to `HazelcastInstance`.

FYI, My project is based on Spring boot, and initiate HazelcastInstance like below (in `ApplicationContextAware` implementation)

```
public static HazelcastInstance getHazelcastIntance(){
    return context.getBean(HazelcastInstance.class) ;
}
```

summary. I would like to know how to register a `Executor` to `HazelcastInstance`.
Thanks.

===============================================

Edit.

I got a `TaskExecutor` bean in my application Context.
But I can not generate `IExecutorService` with Spring `TaskExecutor` bean.

```
IExecutorService executor = hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService("taskExecutor");
executor.execute(new ParallelDBSyncExecutor(executeId) {
          @Override
          public void action() throws Exception {
                            this.dbSyncService.executeWithIteration(this.executeId, start, total);
          }
});
```

Hazelcast can detect Spring bean which is already registered?

Comment: What do you mean buy register the ExecutorService? As a Spring bean? You need to create a Producer method which will get the HazelcastInstance injected (to have the right dependency order) and returns the ExecutorService to be registered as a bean.

Comment: @noctarius yes... but I still do not understand what is difference with `IExecutorService` and `ExecutorService`. As far as I know, they uses different packages, I think it is natural that they could not find each other. I will add more details to the post..

Comment: IExecutorService is a distributed version of the normal Java ExecutorService. Submitted Callables / Runnables are executed in the cluster not locally (therefore they must be serializable somehow).